# Flash Memory in 8051F340 Microcontroller gets erased

Tags: c, microcontroller, 8051, flash-memory

Well I hope this question fits to Stackoverflow ( if otherwise, I want to apologize already )

I have can C8051F340 Microcontroller from Silabs. I wrote a little Interface which stores Information in the non-volatile flash memory from the uC. Now as in the data sheet described I save all the data in between the addresses 0x0200 - 0x0300. To copy my data there I just use memcpy.

```
char xdata *ptr_selection       = 0x0210;
// Some other code here
memcpy (ptr_selection, writeBuffer, sizeof (writeBuffer));
```

Well the copying itself works well ( I looked up at the flash memory and it saved my data right ) - If I now disconnect my uC and connect it again in like 5 secs, the data is still there. But if I leave it disconnected any longer my data gets more or less "resetted" - that means it gets everytime almost the same "reset values". so what am I doing wrong? I mean isnt the flash data non volatile or did I get something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the code you displayed in your question, you are trying to write to external data (xdata), which is RAM, not non-volatile flash memory.  The reason the data disappears after a few seconds, is the power supply capacitor still powers the chip long enough to keep the internal RAM alive.

To write to flash memory, you need to follow a specific protocol to unlock the flash programming circuitry, then erase the area you will be writing to, and then write the bytes using MOVX instructions as described in Section 12 of the datasheet.

This Silicon Labs application note ["Writing to Flash from Firmware"](http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/an201.pdf) describes the process in detail.

Comment: Yea according to the datasheet I need to unlock it ( there is a procedure described there ) but how do I pick a destination? I mean there can only be one address 0x0200 ?! And how do I do it in C? Is there any way?

Comment: Okay that link to the application note from silabs helped. Down there  I tried to implement the example for the F340 into my code. But actually if I call the FLASH_ByteWrite Function nothing happens -> if I debug and step into it I see that the second parameter isnt changed at all... so e.g. if I call FLASH_ByteWrite(0x0200, 0xFF) and then step into the function the variable for the second parameter is zero in the function itself..?

Comment: Re your question re the MOVX instruction, the app note says: "When the PSWE bit (PSCTL.0) is set to a logic 1, MOVX write opcodes target Flash memory
instead of External  Memory (XRAM). When both PSWE and PSEE (PSCTL.0 and PSCTL.1)  are set to logic 1,
MOVX write opcodes erase the Flash page containing the target address."

Comment: Not sure why your stepping into function call would how the wrong parameter.  However I question your use of 0x200 for a Flash address to use for data, that would normally be right in the middle of where your code is placed, unless you have modified your linker script.  You should pick an address toward the top of your flash memory, like 0xF000.

Comment: Yeah youre right, 0x0200 was not the best idea, but according to the datasheet and the AP 0x2000 should be right. Actually you helped me a lot in making progress - I still have some weird problem left. I use the example functions from the AP for the F340. It compiles without problems, but like i already said, it has problems with passing the function parameters... For example: If I call the function like its designed it doesnt work - if I make a global variable to "pass" the function arguments it works....I don't know why that is...???

Comment: Okay now it kinda works, I still cant debug right into the functions, but at least if I look at the memory I see it gets changed - so close enough for me ^^ . Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

Flash memory is not like oridnary SRAM, SDRAM memory.

You can not just write to it. Maximum that you can - read from it as from
normal memory (only if you have NOR flash).

But if you want to write to it,
you have to the first of all erase it (set all bits to 1).
Only then you can write to it.
Normaly, erasing done by sectors. They called erase sectors.
See datasheet of your microcontroller about their size.

PS

Acording to datasheet of your CPU, to write you have to use  special instruction.
Make sure that memcpy internally use it.